# Hibernate 5.1 with Postgis 2.2 geometry columns mapping

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, postgis

Documentation for hibernate 5.1 spatial is not yet released (AFAIK) and I'm trying to persist entities with JST geometries fields to PostgreSQL 9.5 + Postgis 2.2, without any luck.

I've also noticed that there is no org.hibernate.spatial package in hibernate-core-5.1.0. I've tried variations of the following annotation:

```
@javax.persistence.Column(name = "the_geom", columnDefinition = "Geometry")
public com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry geom;
```

When columnDefinition is set to "Point" I get "column "the_geom" is of type point but expression is of type bytea". In hibernate spatial 4 documentation it is said that the @Type annotation would not be needed from releases 5+, but what should be used instead? How to store the geom as a valid Postgis geometry?

Comment: Hi @Mihai I've the same issue right now with the same configuration and dependencies. I search for a while without any result, did you spot anything that drive at least what is the cause of the issue?

Comment: Hi @Dario, due to the lack of time I downgraded to hibernate 4.3 for the moment. I'm waiting for the official documentation to be available.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while I found a solution that fits my needs (I'm hoping also yours). Due to the fact that with version 5 all the `jts` and `geolatte` geometry types are capable of been managed directly by hibernate you should configure hibernate to manage those types.

In my scenario I manage all the configuration in a spring `@Configuration` class: there, as shown in the "*example 9*" of [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type) I decided to use the `MetadataBuilder` approach as follows:

```
@Bean
public static MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder() {

    ServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build();
    MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources( standardRegistry );
    return sources.getMetadataBuilder();
}

@Bean
public static MetadataBuilder spatialConfiguration() {

    JTSGeometryType jtsGeometryType = new JTSGeometryType(PGGeometryTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE);
    return PersistenceConfiguration.metadataBuilder().applyBasicType(jtsGeometryType);
}
```

In this way all my `jts` geometries (there is also the other for `geolatte` geometries `org.hibernate.spatial.GeolatteGeometryType`) are mapped correctly as declare in my database model.

Hopes this can help you,

Dario.

Comment: I decided to stick with hibernate 4.3 for the moment, and I haven't tested your solution yet. I will migrate to 5.* sometime in the near future and validate this/accept answer. Thanks.

Comment: WIth 5.2.3.Final version of hibernate jts geometries are supported by default, without the need for extra configuration. I'm using JTS 1.13 version.

Comment: where does JTSGeometryType and PGGeometryTypeDescriptor come from?